# How to import a python file from another folder in Python 3.5 on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I use Python 3.5 and my project structure is like this:

```
Project/
    App/
        myApp.py
    Libraries/
        myLibA.py
        myLibB.py
```

I want to import `myLibA.py` in `myApp.py`

If I simply write `from Libraries import myLibA` I end up with this error :

> ImportError: No module named Libraries.

I found the Q/A [Importing files from different folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python), from which I adapted my own solution, adding this at the beginning of `myApp.py` in order to add my `Project` folder to the Python Path :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0] + "..")
```

This worked well on Windows, but when I run `myApp.py` from the same project on OSX (10.9) I see the same error message, my module is not found.

To reproduce my issue it's very simple. Just fill the Python files like this :

**myApp.py** :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0] + "..")

from Libraries import myLibA

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myLibA.print_hello()
```

**myLibA.py** :

```
def print_hello():
    print("Hello")
```

I don't understand why the Python Path method doesn't work here. Anyway, I'm looking for a solution that keeps the Python file compatible with Windows and that is contained in the sources (in the Python files). I've seen a few console hooks but I'm not satisfied with that because I want to be able to clone the project on any OSX/Windows PC with Python 3.5, and just run myApp.py. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve any library not natively present in Python 3.5.

Is there another way to achieve this ?

(If not, is it because it is somehow not *pythonic* to organize a project like this? As a C developer I might have the wrong approach)

Comment: Does `Libraries` has an `__init__.py` in it?  If not then an empty one will do:  `touch __init__.py`.  Second:  don't use relative path names (..), you are asking for trouble, use absolute path names, or use environment variables (like `os.environ['HOME']`).

Comment: @cdarke they don't, I thought it was a Python 2 thing. The problem with an absolute path is that I don't know in advance at which location the project will be cloned.

Comment: You also will not know the current directory of the process running `python` either.   Should it be relative to the directory that your script resides in, for example?  As a C programmer, you wouldn't do a `#include('../fred.h')` would you?

Comment: @cdarke That's right I assumed the current process directory would be the one containing myApp.py. As a C programmer I'd just include "fred.h" and tell the linker to look for the files in all the project folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `__init__.py` to your `Libraries` directory.  That file can be empty, and it  magically turns the `Libraries` directory into a [*package*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).  Now:

```
import sys
import os.path
libdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.split(libdir)[0])   

from Libraries import myLibA

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myLibA.print_hello()
```

The `__file__` special variable gives the filename of the current script.  `os.path.dirname()` gives the directory it resides in, and `os.path.split(libdir)[0]` gives its parent directory.  This should work wherever the script is called from.

I am using `append` rather than `insert`.  It is generally advised that user directories are searched last, and also `append` is more efficient than `insert` in the C Python implementation.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine both on Windows and OSX. I was sure that the __init__.py file was only required in Python 2, and that Python 3 wasn't using it. Was I wrong about this ?

Comment: Generally `__init__.py` is used on both.  At 3.3 *Namespace Packages* were introduced, but those are for splitting a package across directories. I have not seen them used much and I don't think that is appropriate in your case.  See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/.  The point about `__init__.py` is that it can contain initialisation code for the *package*, including defining functions.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should have `__init__.py` inside every folder that you want to import.
Also a common project structure for a python project is this:

```
Project/ 
Libraries/         <-- this will contain app specific code (Libraries)
    __init__.py
    myLibA.py
    myLibB.py
main.py
```

Where main.py will contain the entry code of you app, just like C's main(), for example

```
from Libraries import myLibA

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myLibA.print_hello()
```

No need to tinker with sys.path in runtime.

Comment: Thank you, that's the correct solution, though someone posted it a few seconds before you ;) Just correct me if I'm wrong, but if I don't modify that Path at runtime I have the risk that someone who clones the project on a location that is not in the Path will have an import error as long has he doesn't add the project location to the path, is that right ?

Comment: With the above structure you won't have any issues, there is no need to add anything to path. Just run `python /path/to/Project/main.py`. The "path" we refer to in python is the path where python looks for packages (folders with __init__py inside), and  the folder of the main.py ("Project" in this case) is already in the python path.

Comment: Oh that's right thanks. But my files will not be at the same level than Libraries. I think that's why I need to modify the path.

Comment: if you insist to put them in an "app" directory, then go ahead, modify the path but I dont think it 's worth it. But instead of adding '..' in the path, search google for getting the folder of a file in python

Comment: The thing is that I oversimplified my current Project structure for asking this question, but I actually have a high amount of myApp.py files, all with a main function, etc. I put them in a subfolder to keep the Project folder as clean as possible.

Answer (score 2):

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) is somewhat similar. My favourite answer suggests a project structure like this in your case:

```
Project/
    myApp.py
    Libraries/
        __init__.py
        myLibA.py
        myLibB.py
```

With the library code in `myLibA.py` unchanged the app code and import would look like this:

```
from Libraries import myLibA

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myLibA.print_hello()
```

**Edit 1:**

When the requested folder structure is necessary, this change to the  `myApp.py` file:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".."))
```

works too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it would work, but I want to put myApp.py in a subfolder. I simplified my usecase a lot for asking the question, but actually I have plenty of files such as myApp1.py, myApp2.py, etc, so I prefer to put them all in a subfolder.